# What should I use to create a piano app? ImageView,etc?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I don't know what kind of widget should i use for my piano app.

I've tried to use an ImageView for the keys and attached a setOnTouchListener to it.
It works but somehow the image should finish the sound it produced before you can press it again.I used MediaPlayer for the sounds. I also want to make the "slide" thing with the keys and i was trying to use this lines of code:

```
final MediaPlayer whiteP1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.white_1);
white1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

// to make the keys work (produce sounds) i removed this line of codes:
   int i = event.getAction(); // i removed this line and the if statement and left the whiteP1.start();
if(i == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
{ 
whiteP1.start(); 
}
return false;
}
});
```

problem is it doesn't work on the emulator and when i tried it on an android phone, it didn't work.

i also used RelativeLayout to make the white and black keys of the piano overlap with each other. I don't know if it works perfectly with every screen resolution and i want your opinions regarding this one too.

any help would be appreciated. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You are blocking the GUI thread with this code. Create a thread, and play the media on the other thread. And the best way to do the same is to make use of the AsynTask class. But in this case you can make use of much simplified runnable method. Take a look.

```
final MediaPlayer whiteP1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.white_1);
white1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int i = event.getAction();
                whiteP1.start();
                if(i == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)    {
                    whiteP1.start();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
});
```

I have not tested this code, but it should probably work. Feel free to ask if you have nay questions.

Comment: I tried it and it worked but if i press the key twice it would only produce one sound and will wait for the sound to finish before you can press it again. And when i tried to do the "slide" thing like on a piano it won't work.

Comment: i also got an error whenever i try to use public void, therefore i used public boolean and returned it to false.